# OSError file not found when navigating through sub-directories in python?

Tags: python

There is a directory tree structure such that article is main folder and d10x are the subfolders

```
/articles
  /d101
    1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
  /d102
    1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
  /d103
    1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
  /d104
  .....
  .....
  .....
  /d200
```

My program has to go to each of the subfolder and read a text file from it.
My python implementation gets the following error 
**OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'd101'** 
Python code:

```
articles = os.listdir("articles")
mo=[]
for yo in articles:
  mo.append(yo)
for index in range(len(mo)):
  yo=os.listdir(mo[index])
  for article in yo:
     print 'Reading articles/' + article
```

**OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'd101'**

Comment: unrelated: use `for item in alist: print(item)` instead of `for i in range(len(alist)): print(alist[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read `d101` instead of `articles/d101`.  Change your `listdir()` call to this:

```
os.listdir(os.path.join("articles", mo[index]))
```